# How can i create nested array in android studio Strings.xml

Tags: android

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">UnConv</string>
    <string-array name="mainunit">
        <item>Area</item>
        <item>Pressure</item>
        <item>Speed</item>
        <item>Volume</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

i want to add some other values to the above items like a subgroup. Example for area i want yard, acre etc how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, There is no direct way to save two dimensional string-array in Android resource file. I provide 2 methods for replacement.

**1**. Save the data as Json string showing in the following code:

```
<string name="mainunit">{&quot;Area&quot;:[&quot;yard&quot;,&quot;acre&quot;],&quot;Pressure&quot;:[],&quot;Speed&quot;:[],&quot;Volume&quot;:[]}</string>
```

Then parse Json String to Java/Kotlin Object.

**2**. Save subgroup value splitting with "**,**", and get value by position, but it has drawback because it ignored the key name.

```
<string-array name="mainunit">
        <item>yard,acre</item>
        <item>Pressure</item>
        <item>Speed</item>
        <item>Volume</item>
</string-array>
```